# UK noise certificate for below 9000kg?

Tags: noise, uk

This is regarding UK regulation - [The Air Navigation (Noise Certification) Order 1990](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1990/1514/made). I am curious what is the reason of specify this particular upper weight limit here:

"*every propeller driven aeroplane having a maximum total weight authorised of 9,000kg or less;*"?

Just a bit below there is another point:

"*every other subsonic aeroplane which in accordance with its certificate of airworthiness has a take-off distance required, at maximum total weight authorised on a hard level runway in still air in an International Standard Atmosphere at sea level, of more than 610 metres;*".

I suppose there is some class of aeroplanes that somehow falls between these two categories (what is it?), otherwise what sens would that inclusions/exclusions make?